# redirecting to another port gets ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location

Tags: apache, ubuntu

I'm trying to redirect a request to another port, but I'm getting this error:

```
ProxyPass|ProxyPassMatch can not have a path when defined in a location.
```

This is my virtual host redirect:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName sub.domain.com.br
        DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx
        ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com.br
        Options -Indexes

        ProxyRequests On
        ProxyPreserveHost On

        <Proxy *>
            Order deny,allow
            Allow from all
        </Proxy>

        <Location />
                ProxyPass /route/ www.sub.domain.com.br:31311/
                ProxyPassReverse /route/ www.sub.domain.com.br:31311/
        </Location>

        ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot_error.log
        CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot_access.log combined


</VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 2):

The `ProxyPass` and `ProxyPassReverse` clauses nested within `<location>` section have to have the first parameter omitted. This also makes some sense - the proxied "pseudo-location" has to be defined on the `<location XXX>` level.

So, to your example config. Consider doing alterations to it like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName sub.domain.com.br
    DocumentRoot /var/www/html/xxx
    ServerAlias www.sub.domain.com.br
    Options -Indexes

    ProxyRequests On
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    <Proxy *>
        Order deny,allow
        Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location /route/>                                 # <==
        ProxyPass www.sub.domain.com.br:31311/         # <==
        ProxyPassReverse www.sub.domain.com.br:31311/  # <==
    </Location>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot_error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/bot_access.log combined
</VirtualHost>
```